# unmet dependencies when Installing NVidia 460 driver

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 20.04

it seems I am not able to upgrade from 450 driver to 460. Following is the output:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar  2 10:12:34 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1086MiB /  2000MiB |     36%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1421      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                192MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6321      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                459MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6494      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              332MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7090      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8188      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9017      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9064      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9227      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9731      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12448      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     24608      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     99825      G   .../.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam       33MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     99834      G   ./steamwebhelper                    1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     99847      G   ...AAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --log-f       39MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

I checked online and people say to do purge first, but I suspect that it won't work. I am wondering is there anyone went through the path of this upgrade? Or should I wait for the next driver?

Comment: Do you have the `restricted` repo enabled?  `sudo add-apt-repository restricted`  That is where those dependencies come from.

Comment: @Terrance yes, `'restricted' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` but I am not sure if it'll solve your problem.

> people say to do purge first, but I suspect that it won't work

Why do you suspect this? Per nvidia docs you have to purge the older version before you can install a new one. Try:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo apt autoremove
```

You might have to restart at this point (If you get a blank screen, don't panic. You can login using alt-ctrl-F1 and install the new nvidia driver or switch to using nouveau till your install is done)

Comment: I read some people said it didn't work for them. I suppose I should pick a day and try myself. I will still have gui after I purge (like swtich back to xorg)?

Comment: It is a bit cumbersome for sure, but has improved a lot in recent versions. You will still have your gui after restart (if you switch over to nouveau) but you can also work through a terminal